# How to write Flutter Unit Test that calls Python function through Chaquopy?

Tags: flutter, dart, chaquopy

How do I create a `Flutter` unit test that uses `Chaquopy` to call Python code `Chaquopy.executeCode(python_code_string)`?

Tried running the following Flutter test

```
import 'package:chaquopy/chaquopy.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  test('hello world', () async {
    final _result = await Chaquopy.executeCode("my_python_module.hello('world)");
    expect(_result['textOutputOrError'], 'hello world');
  });
}
```

but it is failing with the error

```
  Binding has not yet been initialized.
  The "instance" getter on the ServicesBinding binding mixin is only available once that binding has been initialized.
  Typically, this is done by calling "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" or "runApp()" (the latter calls the former). Typically this call is done in the "void main()" method. The "ensureInitialized" method is idempotent; calling it multiple times is not harmful. After calling that method, the "instance" getter will return the binding.
  In a test, one can call "TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" as the first line in the test's "main()" method to initialize the binding.
  If ServicesBinding is a custom binding mixin, there must also be a custom binding class, like WidgetsFlutterBinding, but that mixes in the selected binding, and that is the class that must be constructed before using the "instance" getter.
  package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart 302:9          BindingBase.checkInstance.<fn>
  package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart 383:6          BindingBase.checkInstance
  package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart 55:54            ServicesBinding.instance
  package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 136:25  _findBinaryMessenger
  package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 269:56  MethodChannel.binaryMessenger
  package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 303:15  MethodChannel._invokeMethod
  package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 483:12  MethodChannel.invokeMethod
  package:chaquopy/chaquopy.dart 13:41                       Chaquopy.executeCode
  test/hello_world_test.dart 6:36                             main.<fn>
```

What should I do to set up this unit test to run properly?

I am using `Chaquopy 12.0.1`, [`chaquopy_flutter` plugin](https://github.com/jaydangar/chaquopy_flutter) and `Flutter 3.10.4`.